# Ajax post returning undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, flask

I am trying to send the value of what is in the div's on the post via ajax.

Specifically I'm trying to send what is in the div slick-active, so in this example console.log(data.results); would show 4 and 6

Here is the html:

```
          <div class="slider single-item">
              <div class="slick-slide"><h3>1</h3></div>
              <div class="slick-slide"><h3>2</h3></div>
              <div class="slick-slide"><h3>3</h3></div>
              <div class="slick-slide slick-active"><h3>4</h3></div>
              <div class="slick-slide"><h3>5</h3></div>

          <div class="slider single-item">
              <div class="slick-slide slick-active"><h3>6</h3></div>
              <div class="slick-slide"><h3>7</h3></div>
              <div class="slick-slide"><h3>8</h3></div>
              <div class="slick-slide"><h3>9</h3></div>
              <div class="slick-slide"><h3>10</h3></div>
```

Here is the ajax/jquery

```
      $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#submit').on('click', function(e){
                  e.preventDefault(); // preventing default click action

                  $.ajax({
                    url: '/testing',
                    type: 'post',
                    data: JSON.stringify({results: $('#div.slick-active')}),
                      success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                      // ajax success callback
                    }, error: function (response) {
                      alert('ajax failed');
                      // ajax error callback
                    },
                  });
                });
```

Serverside Flask route

```
@app.route('/testing', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def testing():
        r = request.json
        print r
        return "data recived is %s" % r
```

Which returns console.log r as None, which should instead return 4,6

Comment: Maybe `console.log(data)`? General tip: Set a breakpoint and inspect your own code and data in your browser's developer tools before asking "does not work" questions.

Comment: Does `/testing` route return something? Cause `data` is the result from the script you post to. You might want to show the script (`/testing`) cause its probably there the issue is.

Comment: `$('#div.slick-active')` will return a jQuery object and not the text inside the divs. You should use something like `$('#div.slick-active').text()` instead.

Comment: @Tomalak Ok noted thank you.  Yes the /testing goes to a flask route.  I will take it out for testing.  Let me try the #div

Comment: @Jite I updated to show server side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call: `$('#div.slick-active')` you are selecting each object with the ID `div` that has the class `slick-active`, the call will return a list of jquery objects, but in your case, none, due to not having a single element with the `div` ID.

So to start, you wish to select on element instead of id, the selector would look something like:  `$('div.slick-active')` (without the `#` which indicates ID).

Now, this will still return a list of `jquery` objects, something you don't really want to send to your script.

Personally, I never fetch the inner-html or text from a element as a value, if you can, add a `data-value` attribute with the value of the item, like:

```
<div class="slick-slide" data-value="1"><h3>1</h3></div>
```

So, its still a `jquery` object, and you only want the value.
So, you need to fetch it from each of the objects in the list that is returned.

This can be done by using the array method [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), which iterates the objects and calls a function you create on each, whatever the function returns will be returned as an array at the end of the iteration.

This could look something like:

```
$('div.slick-active').map(function($ele) {
    // Here we select the 'data-value' from the object and return it.
    return $ele.data('value'); 
}
```

Now, this can be done without adding the data-value attribute to the elements in the html, but then you need to select the value of the h3 inside the element, which would make the return from the map function look something like this:

```
return $ele.find('h3').text();
```

But I would recommend adding the data-value attribute!

Comment: Thank you so much, added in a data-value and its working now!

Comment: Glad to hear, happy to help.

Answer (score 2):

Succes callback returns the response from server, not the parameters that you provide on the request. Try just `console.log(data)` and see what the result is. It can be empty. Additionally, check the status of the returned response, if you save posted data on the server side, it should return 201 Created.

Just a hint: from jQuery 1.8 the .success(..) and .error(..) methods are deprecated. From jQuery documentation:

> Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and
>   jqXHR.complete() callbacks are deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. To prepare
>   your code for their eventual removal, use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(),
>   and jqXHR.always() instead.

Comment: it reutns 201 and success.  Returns my route.  But for some reason it is not actually sending the data in the div.  I tried as suggested in the comments $('#div.slick-active').text() but still does not show that on the server.

Comment: $('#div.slick-active') is incorrect jQuery selection expression, you should use # for id not the class, it should be rather $('div.slick-active').text()